# WPF : control visibility does not render in a command after the first time

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Working on a MVVM WPF form.

I'm using a RelayCommand to:

1) change a control visibility

2) run a long process

3) update control's visibility back

Command code is as follows:

```
    private RelayCommand _MyCommand;
    public RelayCommand MyCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _MyCommand
                ?? (_MyCommand = new RelayCommand(
                () =>
                {
                        //1 update control's visibility
                        GridViewVisibility = false;


                        //deleting a reference is done via multithreading as the process is quite long (10 sec)
                        Task.Run(() =>
                        {

                            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((new Action(() =>
                            {
                                //2 looong process here


                                //3 update control's visibility
                                GridViewVisibility = true;
                            }
                       )));
                        }
                        );

                } ));
        }
    }
```

Systematically, when I run the command for the first time, it works perfectly. The controls visibility updates as expected (before and after the process).

But when I trigger the command again, operation 2 is still performed.
The code that updates the visibility is reached but does not render (1 and 3). so the control's visibility is not updated.

Any idea why????

Comment: Why are you invoking the long process through the dispatcher? Shouldn't you run the long process in the task, and once that is finished update the `GridViewVisibility` through the Dispatcher?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this behavior is random and not first/next basis.

Comment: As @Maarten suggests, you could remove the `Task.Run` and `Dispatcher.Invoke` and be in pretty much the same situation.  You're still blocking the UI thread for the whole of your operation, so it's not too surprising that the UI doesn't update.